# Regular expression for checking any word of at least one letter

Tags: php

Regular expression for  checking  any word of at least one letter

examples:

fish (right)
fish12 (right)
123 (wrong)
T  (right)
12n(right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're inputting a word at a time then simply check:

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

because if you find a letter it's a word. If you have a stream of words it gets a little more difficult.

To find words that contain at least one letter:

```
\b([a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

> use preg_match function

```
 
$str ="1234a";
if ( preg_match ( '/[A-Za-z]{1,}/',$str ,$val ) ) 
{ 
print "right" ; 
print_r ( $val ) ;
} 
else 
{ 
print "wrong " ; 
}
```

It prints right;

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/a-zA-Z/
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP functions as well

```
if( strlen($string)>1 && ctype_alnum($string) ){
  print "ok\n";
}
```